# My application: Label show a value which should increase or decrease when i press button

Tags: c++, gtk

I created an application which contains 4 labels. I want to change the value of two labels ("wynik" and "wynik1"). When I press key left on the keyboard "wynik" label's value should increase, when I press key down decrease.  When I press key right "wynik1" label's value should increase, when I press key up decrease.
My code:

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    #include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>

    gint count = 0;
    char buf[0];
    char buf1[0];


    gboolean
    on_key_press (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer wynik);
    gboolean
    on_key_press1 (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer wynik);

    int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
        GtkWidget * okno;
        GtkWidget * kontener;
        GtkWidget * etykieta;
        GtkWidget * etykieta1;
        GtkWidget * wynik;
        GtkWidget * wynik1;

        gtk_init( & argc, & argv );

        okno = gtk_window_new( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL );
        gtk_window_set_keep_above(GTK_WINDOW(okno), TRUE);
        gtk_window_set_default_size( GTK_WINDOW( okno ), 300, 200 );
        gtk_window_set_position( GTK_WINDOW( okno ), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER );

        kontener = gtk_fixed_new();
        gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER( okno ), kontener );

        char * str = " <span fgcolor='#007560'><span font='20'><b>PIA</b></span></span>";
        etykieta = gtk_label_new( NULL );
        gtk_label_set_markup( GTK_LABEL( etykieta ), str );
        gtk_fixed_put( GTK_FIXED( kontener ), etykieta, 0, 0 );

        char * str1 = " <span fgcolor='#9a1262'><span font='20'><b>PER</b></span></span>";
        etykieta1 = gtk_label_new( NULL );
        gtk_label_set_markup( GTK_LABEL( etykieta1 ), str1 );
        gtk_fixed_put( GTK_FIXED( kontener ), etykieta1, 65, 0 );

        char * wyn = " <span fgcolor='#007560'><span font='26'><b>0</b></span></span>";
        wynik = gtk_label_new( NULL );
        gtk_label_set_markup( GTK_LABEL( wynik ), wyn );
        gtk_fixed_put( GTK_FIXED( kontener ), wynik, 3, 30 );

        char * wyn1 = " <span fgcolor='#9a1262'><span font='26'><b>0</b></span></span>";
        wynik1 = gtk_label_new( NULL );
        gtk_label_set_markup( GTK_LABEL( wynik1 ), wyn1 );
        gtk_fixed_put( GTK_FIXED( kontener ), wynik1, 68, 30 );

        g_signal_connect( G_OBJECT( okno ), "destroy", G_CALLBACK( gtk_main_quit ), NULL );
        g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (okno), "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK (on_key_press), wynik);
        g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (okno), "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK (on_key_press1), wynik1);
        gtk_widget_show_all( okno );
        gtk_main();

        return 0;
    }

    gboolean
    on_key_press (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer wynik)
    {
    switch (event->keyval)
      {case GDK_S:
        case GDK_Left:
            count++;
            std::ostringstream os;
            os << "<span font='26'><b>" << count << "</b></span>";
            gtk_label_set_markup( GTK_LABEL( wynik ), os.str().c_str() );
          break;
        case GDK_Down:
            count--;
            std::ostringstream os;
            os << "<span font='26'><b>" << count << "</b></span>";
            gtk_label_set_markup( GTK_LABEL( wynik ), os.str().c_str() );
          break;

        default:
          return FALSE;
      }    
      return FALSE;
    }

 gboolean
    on_key_press1 (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer wynik1)
    {
    switch (event->keyval)
      {case GDK_S:  // add this line
        case GDK_Right:
            count++;
            std::ostringstream os1;
            os1 << "<span font='26'><b>" << count << "</b></span>";
            gtk_label_set_markup( GTK_LABEL( wynik1 ), os1.str().c_str() );
          break;
        case GDK_Up:
            count--;
            std::ostringstream os1;
            os1 << "<span font='26'><b>" << count << "</b></span>";
            gtk_label_set_markup( GTK_LABEL( wynik1 ), os1.str().c_str() );
          break;

        default:
          return FALSE;
      }    
      return FALSE;
    }
```

Unfortunatelly i get errors:

> ```
> > ||=== nowygt3, Debug ===| F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c||In function
> > 'on_key_press':| F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|67|error: expected expression
> > before ':' token| F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|68|error: 'os' undeclared
> > (first use in this function)| F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|68|note: each
> > undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it
> > appears in| F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|73|error: duplicate label 'std'|
> > F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|67|note: previous definition of 'std' was here|
> > F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|73|error: expected expression before ':' token|
> > F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|67|warning: label 'std' defined but not used
> > [-Wunused-label]| F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c||In function 'on_key_press1':|
> > F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|91|error: expected expression before ':' token|
> > F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|92|error: 'os1' undeclared (first use in this
> > function)| F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|97|error: duplicate label 'std'|
> > F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|91|note: previous definition of 'std' was here|
> > F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|97|error: expected expression before ':' token|
> > F:\c++\nowygt3\main.c|91|warning: label 'std' defined but not used
> > [-Wunused-label]|
> ```

Please help me. I'm really beginner but I try to do everything by myself and now I have no ideas.

Comment: did you forget to #include <iostream> ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be complaining about 
`std::ostringstream os1;`

did you `#include <iostream>` ?

Answer (score 0):

To create an object with automatic storage duration within the specific `case` of `switch` statement:

```
case GDK_S:
case GDK_Left:
    std::ostringstream os;
    ...
    break;
```

you should define the scope, which lifetime of `os` will be tied to:

```
case GDK_S:
case GDK_Left:
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    ...
    break;
}
```

Apart from that you should also `#include <sstream>` to be able to use [`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/).

Comment: I cannot add answer for 6 hours so i update my first post. Please help me:)